# Moving a rectangle regarding another rectangle rotation

Tags: math, geometry, rectangles

I have two rectangles: red and green. For each of them, I have the following information:

- Center point (`x` and `y` coords).
- Rotation angle
- Width and height

The rectangles *will always be* moving in positive coordinates. **Edit:** No coordinate can ever be negative: the rectangles are always located in positive coordinates. Therefore, the center *will never be* (0,0).

**Problem**

I have an starting position. To simplify the example, let's say that my red and green rectangles are located as follows:

[image]

Now, I rotate the red rectangle using an angle `phi` which goes between 0º and 90º.  However, the green rectangles needs to *rotate and keep its position regarding the red rectangle.* The green rectangle is not only rotating *but also moving*.

Let see an image (please excuse the sketch-quality):

[image]

**My Question:**

How can I obtain the new center coords for the green rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation is about some point `(rx, ry)`.

**Edit:** As comment says, rotation center `(rx, ry)` is red center. **Formula remains the same.**

If green center was at `(gx, gy)`, then after rotation it has coordinates

```
 gx' = rx + (gx - rx) * Cos(Phi) - (gy - ry) * Sin(Phi)
 gy' = ry + (gx - rx) * Sin(Phi) + (gy - ry) * Cos(Phi)
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It is not rotating the green rectangle *on its own*, but rotating it while keeping its position relative to the red rectangle. This is to say: I rotate the **red** rectangle, and the green one needs to rotate and "travel" to keep its position relative to the red rectangle. It is not a simple rotation.

Comment: Again: rotation is around some point. If both rectangles preserve mutual orientation - this point is the same for both rectangles (they undergo the same affine transformation). What is this rotation center?

Comment: The rotation center will always be the red rectangle's center -not the green's. Therefore, the green rectangle needs to rotate and travel: the position of the green rectangle is relative to the red one. Green does not rotate on itself.

Comment: OK, formula for new position of green center is still right. Green rectangle rotates around red center

Comment: OK. Also check Phi angle sign thoroughly (formula might depend on system handedness and its interpretation by human)